# Centos 6.2 on vmware, kernel update, doesn't boot

Tags: vmware, centos

I updated Centos 6.2 on virtual machine (vmware)

```
yum -y upgrade kernel kernel-devel
```

But after reboot machine, failed to boot. How could I retrive my data on that machine hard disk?

Comment: This is almost certainly a very easy issue to solve. Why don't you post **a new** question about getting your OS back? Mention which boot loader you use (`grub`?), if you have a rescue option in the boot loader, if you can boot from a live CD and if so, show the contents of `/boot`.

Comment: I tried to use old kernel but I get an error: `VFS: Cannot open root device "sda5" or unknown block (0,0) please append a correct "root=" boot option`

Comment: Please post a new question about this. It is a different issue. If the answer below gives you access to your drives (which is what this Q is about), consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving your data is not a problem, the easiest approach would be to download any Linux live CD and boot from it. From the live session, you will be able to access your drive with no problem and easily copy data somewhere else. Just open a file manager, and click to mount the drives.

Using Gnome's `nautilus`:

[image]

Using KDE's **Dolphin**:

[image]

The images above were <del>stolen</del> taken from a very nice [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190239/how-to-access-hard-drive-files-from-livecd) by [@Peachy](https://askubuntu.com/users/74307/peachy) over on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I could do it but not for files under /home/user/ files. I haven't permission to view or copy that files.

Comment: @JalalJaberi yes you will. In the live CD, you will have root access, permissions will not be an issue.

Comment: I did that. I used an ubuntu live CD and tried to open user folder. But I got permission error. However I solved problem with changing boot options. thank you for your help. This post may help other visitors. ;)